# Oracle Database Creation

Tags: oracle, database-administration

what is the meaning of this paragraph 
" Creating a database can also erase information in an existing database and create a new database with the same name and physical structure."
and what is the steps to perform this type of Oracle database creation

Comment: where did you read that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67772/create.htm#997674

Comment: Note that the documentation you referenced is something like 25 years old. While I'm not sure it matters for this particular question, you should make sure you're looking at something current (or at least for the version you're working with specifically) before making plans.

Comment: I will do that thank you

Comment: Really, 8.1.5 documentation? Even if you find the distribution, it would be a heck of an effort to be able to install them, if feasible. In fact google leads there if you search for create database oracle, No idea how google classifies there results, but there's surely something wrong with the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referring to the "create database" command (see below). The syntax allows specification of various parameters including the database name and specific files for system, other tablespaces, rollback and log files. If required this statement could be used to deliberately replace an existing database I.e. erase and replace it by overwriting the existing files.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67772/create.htm#999193

Comment: so, when the erase action is performed? is it when you provide the old database name in the creation script?

Comment: If you specify the same database name and filenames that overwrite the existing files this will effectively erase the database.

Comment: You can of course remove a database with the Drop Database command or simple delete all of the files that comprise the database at the OS level.